# Why does using a different Java Function instance across different RDDs throw a ClassCastException?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have been working with Spark and ran into a seemingly strange issue. When executing the same Function class (different instances) to the Spark API with different types of RDD - Spark throws a ClassCastException. I have put together some basic code that shows how the concept works when using a `Function` from the Spark package, but does not work when using the Java Util `Function`.

I would like to understand why this happens. I am able to work around this by explicitly using the Spark Function API but not sure what is causing the difference.

This is using Spark-3 and JDK-8.

Below are two tests - one with the SparkFunction that works and one with Java Util Function that fails with the error.

```java
class SparkTest {

    private static final SparkSession sparkSession = createSparkSession();
    private static final JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext());

    private static SparkSession createSparkSession() {
        return SparkSession.builder()
                .config(createSparkConf())
                .getOrCreate();
    }

    private static SparkConf createSparkConf() {
        return new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("Test")
                .setMaster("local")
                .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
    }

    @Test
    void test_withSparkFunctionMapper_succeeds() {
        JavaRDD<Integer> ints = sparkContext.parallelize(Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4));
        JavaRDD<String> strings = sparkContext.parallelize(Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"));

        JavaRDD<Integer> newInts = ints.map(new MySparkMapper<>());
        JavaRDD<String> newStrings = strings.map(new MySparkMapper<>());

        System.out.println(newInts.collect());
        System.out.println(newStrings.collect());
    }

    @Test
    void test_withJavaFunctionMapper_fails() {
        JavaRDD<Integer> ints = sparkContext.parallelize(Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4));
        JavaRDD<String> strings = sparkContext.parallelize(Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"));

        JavaRDD<Integer> newInts = ints.map(new MyJavaMapper<Integer>()::apply);
        JavaRDD<String> newStrings = strings.map(new MyJavaMapper<String>()::apply);

        System.out.println(newInts.collect());
        System.out.println(newStrings.collect());
    }

    private static class MySparkMapper<I> implements org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function<I, I> {

        @Override
        public I call(I i) throws Exception {
            return i;
        }
    }

    private static class MyJavaMapper<I> implements java.util.function.Function<I, I>, Serializable {

        @Override
        public I apply(I i) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$.$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1(JavaPairRDD.scala:1070) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461) at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943) at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943) at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431) at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62) at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49) at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:366) at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:364) at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1431) at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:358) at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:358) at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1431) at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:345) at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:339) at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1431) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:1030) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2236) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497) at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:749)`

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace so that we can see where (in your code and the Spark code) the exception is happening.

Comment: Also, `...java.lang.String and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base...` doesnt look like JDK-8. Modules were added to JDK starting with version **9**.

Comment: Added full stack trace. Previously test was run using JDK-11 targeting JDK-8. I used JDK-8 to compile and run it and updated stack with the information